# Undefined Reference to ldap_simple_bind_s and ldap_init

Tags: c, ldap, header-files, undefined-reference

I tried to bind to a LDAP server (with credentials) but I get undefined reference to ldap functions I use in the program (`ldap_init`, `ldap_simple_bind_s`,etc).

Error message

> Test.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to ldap_init@8 Test.c:(.text+0x60) : undefined reference to ldap_simple_bind_s@12

I have included `ldap.h` header to my code and I have also placed a package of headers and libraries (though I don't know if it is the right one).

What should I do ?

Comment: please include the exact error messages you're getting and the development environment you're using.  The short answer is that your linker isn't finding the libraries.

Comment: Error Msg :
Test.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to ldap_init@8 Test.c:(.text+0x60) : undefined reference to ldap_simple_bind_s@12

Comment: @xaxxon : I understand that my linker doesnt find the libraries required. I am using a MinGW gcc complier to compile the program. I have manually added a set of libraries downloaded from the internet - its novell-cldap-devel pkg. (I guess this is the problem ) I also tried it with openldap v2.4.35. But I get the same error. :(